# Replacing a managed bean instance from the backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

Doing a CRUD, I have a RequestScoped Ticket bean.

I have an XHTML page that until now I have been using to create the new Tickets; the ticket fields are populated directly (`#{ticket.description}` and so on)

Now I have a search form that lists the tickets, and with each ticket a link with the ticket id as a parameter. I want the backing bean to retrieve the ticket bean from EJB/JPA (already done) and put it into the request. I see 3 ways to do so:

- Copy the data from the bean retrieved from JPA into the bean provided by injection. Ugly / prone to omissions.
- Use [ExternalContex#getRequestMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap()) and put the bean there myself. Does not look very proper. Am I right?
- Include my ticket bean into another bean class so I can do `myNewBean.setTicket(ticketFromJpa);`. Seems the best of the options, yet I do not like having to prefix all my EL in the page just for this.

There is out there any cleaner, more proper way of doing what I want?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
To reword what I want, with a little more information. I have a commandLink in page `P1`, that calls action `A` in backing bean `B1`. `B1` does its logic and redirects to page `P2`.
I wanted to set a (request scoped) bean `B2` in action `A`, and that `B2` would be available to draw `P2`.

From experiments, I have found that after leaving action `A` the framework creates a new `B2` request scoped bean, so it looks like that the request scope is shorter than I expected.

The flash scope propesed by Damian looks like it works more like I want, but forces me to redesign the page around #{flash} and that (when I want to use it to create a new bean) I must also add the bean to the flash in an action method (currently it justs goes to the page and the managed bean is available)

I expected a Request scoped bean to be maintained since

Comment: why do you need to put the ticket in the request? what do you want to do next?

Comment: I want to pass the ticket to the .xhtml page so it renders the ticket data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view the ticket in another page, you could do one of the following: 
1) use h:link with a f:param containing the ID of the ticket

```
<h:link value="#{ticket.description}" outcome="/viewTicket" >
    <f:param name="id" value="#{ticket.id}" /
</h:link>
```

Then in the viewTicket.xhtml (or whatever you called the page) you read the ID parameter, and get the ticket from JPA.

This is how the managed would basically look like:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewTicketMBean implements Serializable {

    private String ticketId;
    private Ticket ticket;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ticketId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
        // read ticket from JPA by ID
    }

}
```

2) instead of h:link, if you don't want to expose ticket ID, you can use a commandLink, which before navigating to viewTicket.xhtml, gets the ticket from JPA and puts it in flash scope. Then, in viewTicket you get the ticket from the flash scope. This is how the action method of the commandLink couldl look like

```
Ticket ticket = null;
// get ticket from JPA    
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("ticket", ticket);
return "/viewTicket";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more the first option, please? I am quite new to JSF and so far when I am in the xhtml I just render the data in the managed beans (updated at the backing bean action). How would I call JPA from the xhtml itself?

Comment: I am leaving work now, I'll check the 2nd option later and tell it about how it went.

Comment: I updated the answer. you read the parameter and get the ticket from JPA in the @PostConstruct method of the managed bean. I suggest you study a little more of JSF, read some tutorials, read the docs, etc. This is very basic.

Comment: The flash method is more like I need, yet I found it a little cumbersome (forces me to add the bean to the flash in every action that redirects to the page, and to make reference through flash in EL). Do you know if there is out there any way around these issues?

Comment: Instead of referencing Flash in EL, you can read the bean from flash in the @PostConstruct using this line: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("ticket"); I don't think there's another way to implement this; usually the h:link is used.

Comment: `@ManagedProperty` referring a `#{param}` won't work in a `@ViewScoped`.